# Tkinter window layering

Tags: python, windows-7, tkinter

I have two Tkinter windows, How do I keep one window always on top of the other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't anything you can do AFAIK. According to the [official tk documentation](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/TkCmd/bind.htm#M22),

> ...there is no reliable way to track
>   changes to a window's position in the
>   stacking order.

About the best you could do is to periodically raise one window above the other. I don't recommend that because it may have some really disastrous side effects (for example, making it difficult or impossible for the user to move the window that is always lower than the top-most one)