# Showing Mouseposition with python

Tags: python, linux, tkinter, xlib

I want to track my mouse-position and show that in a tiny window.
For that, I created this piece of code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from Tkinter import *
from Xlib import display

def mousepos():
    data = display.Display().screen().root.query_pointer()._data
    return data["root_x"], data["root_y"]

root = Tk()
strl = "mouse at {0}".format(mousepos())
lab = Label(root,text=strl)
lab.pack()
root.title("Mouseposition")

root.mainloop()
```

This little script shows the mouse-position on startup but doesn't refresh it on mouse-movement. I don't get behind it (did I say that I'm new to python?).
I think I have to use an event from Xlib that tells my script when the mouse is moving...

How do I refresh my mouse-position?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use `root.after` to call `update` periodically.
2. Use `strl = tk.StringVar()` and `tk.Label(...,textvariable=strl)` to
   allow the Label text to change.
3. Call `strl.set()` to change the Label text.
4. A default value for `screenroot` equal to `display.Display().screen().root` was added
   to `mousepos` so that most of that long chain of function calls are
   not repeated every time `mousepos` is called. Calling `mousepos()` without any arguments will continue to work as usual.

---

```
import Tkinter as tk
import Xlib.display as display

def mousepos(screenroot=display.Display().screen().root):
    pointer = screenroot.query_pointer()
    data = pointer._data
    return data["root_x"], data["root_y"]

def update():
    strl.set("mouse at {0}".format(mousepos()))
    root.after(100, update)

root = tk.Tk()
strl = tk.StringVar()
lab = tk.Label(root,textvariable=strl)
lab.pack()
root.after(100, update)
root.title("Mouseposition")
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Perfect! Is there any trick to keep that window in the foreground?

Comment: There probably is, but I don't know the trick. It probably is window-manager and/or OS dependent. According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066359/tkinter-window-layering/4068618#4068618), there is no way to reliably do from it within tk/tcl. According to [this](http://www.daniweb.com/software-development/python/threads/42766/204393#post204393) it is possible to do in Windows by calling `root.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your awesome help :) I'm using debian 6.0 and gnome btw. So, if you remember any trick to keep that window on top, don't hesitate to tell me about it :)